# What is the Java equivalent to Perl's diamond operator <>?

Tags: java, input, io

I am extremely new to Java (just started this weekend) and have a background in Perl. So I have a question:

**What is the Java equivalent to the Perl Diamond Operator (<>)?**

So basically what is Java's equivalent to:

```
print "What is your name?";
my $name = <>;
print "Hello, $name!";
```

Thanks in advance!

---

For those not knowledgeable of Perl:

As used, `<>` is short for `readline(ARGV)`, where `ARGV` is a special file handle that represents either `STDIN` (if no arguments were passed to the program) or the concatenation of the content of the files passed as arguments to the program. `readline` does not remove the line terminator.

Comment: @SLaks The diamond operator reads a stream depending on the value of '$/', which is the equivalent of the shell's `IFS`. When no stream is specified by default, it is stdin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, java is not a  scripting language and it's designed for different things.

Anyhow, similar code in java might look like this:

```
public class Readline {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
        System.out.print("What is your name?");
        java.io.BufferedReader stdin = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String name = stdin.readLine();
        System.out.println("Hello %s\n".format(name));
    }
}
```

Comment: The beauty of the diamond operator in Perl is that it reads from the standart input __unless__ the user specified some input files as arguments. In that case, the diamond operator reads lines from __all__ those files. This code reads only from the STDIN.

Answer (score 5):

That would be `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))` (or `new Scanner(System.in)`, depending on your needs).

Note however that it is not *strictly* equivalent to perl's diamond operator, since the diamond operator is influenced by `$/`. In Java, you'd have to do that differently.

And just for completeness, `System.in` is an `InputStream` (and also happens to be stdin).

Comment: He didn't change `$/`, so that's moot. Does `System.in` read from the file passed as arguments?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there is a Java equivalent as [`<>` does more than just read from `STDIN`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html):

> The null filehandle `<>` is special: it can be used to emulate the behavior of sed and awk. Input from `<>` comes either from standard input, or from each file listed on the command line. Here's how it works: the first time `<>` is evaluated, the [`@ARGV`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#@ARGV) array is checked, and if it is empty, `$ARGV[0]` is set to "-", which when opened gives you standard input. The `@ARGV` array is then processed as a list of filenames. The loop
>
> ```
> while (<>) {
>   ... # code for each line
>   }
> ```
>
> is equivalent to the following Perl-like pseudo code:
>
> ```
>   unshift(@ARGV, '-') unless @ARGV;
>   while ($ARGV = shift) {
>   open(ARGV, $ARGV);
>      while (<ARGV>) {
>      ... # code for each line
>      }
>   }
> ```
>
> except that it isn't so cumbersome to say, and will actually work. It really does shift the `@ARGV` array and put the current filename into the [`$ARGV`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24ARGV) variable. It also uses filehandle [`ARGV`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#ARGV) internally. `<>` is just a synonym for `<ARGV>`, which is magical. (The pseudo code above doesn't work because it treats `<ARGV>` as non-magical.)
>
> Since the null filehandle uses the two argument form of open it interprets special characters, so if you have a script like this:
>
> ```
> while (<>) {
>    print;
> }
> ```
>
> and call it with `perl dangerous.pl 'rm -rfv *|'`, it actually opens a pipe, executes the `rm` command and reads `rm`'s output from that pipe. If you want all items in `@ARGV` to be interpreted as file names, you can use the module [ARGV::readonly](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/ARGV%3a%3areadonly) from CPAN.
>
> You can modify `@ARGV` before the first `<>` as long as the array ends up containing the list of filenames you really want. Line numbers ([`$.`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24.)) continue as though the input were one big happy file. See the example in [eof](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eof.html) for how to reset line numbers on each file.